# Updating multiple instances of a facebook web game

Tags: facebook

## Background

I'm working on a social media game. There is no login screen, a users account is based on their facebook user id. At the moment it is possible for a player to open the game in multiple tabs and when they spend 'in game money' in one window, it's then not updated in the other windows. Allowing players to spend much more money that they have in their account.

## Question

Is it possible to update their remaining money in other instances of the game? Or keep a track of how many instances of the game that single user has open, and log them out?

Comment: When you say money, do you mean in-game virtual currency, or Facebook credits?

Comment: @snipe In-game virtual money, nothing related to Facebook credits.

Comment: This isn't really a Facebook question, more a general problem with synchronising web application state across multiple browser tabs - i'd recommend retagging and clarifying your question so a wider audience will see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to setup in ajax call in jquery or javascript to ping your server to see if the 'in game money' value has changed.  You could also set up some kind of long polling process.